# Unit test error throw in a block

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I'm facing some warning issues in the following case:

```
let expect = expectation(description: "Async network call")
SomeManager.executeCall { result in
    do {
        /// 1.
        XCTAssertThrowsError(try CoreManager.method())
        expect.fulfill()
    } catch {}
}

waitForExpectations(timeout: 15.0, handler: nil)
```

At 1. the compiler gives an error that

> catch block in unreachable because no errors are thrown in do block

and if I remove the do-catch an error is given, that:

> Invalid conversion from throwing function type to non-throwing function type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `XCTAssertThrowsError` swallows the error, so you should not need a do/catch. 
Looks like a bug to me. 
As a workaround try to wrap the check function like this

```
func mustThrow() {
   XCTAssertThrowsError(try CoreManager.method())
}
```

and then call

```
SomeManager.executeCall { result in
    /// 1.
    mustThrow()
    expect.fulfill()
}
```

you can define the function locally in the test to avoid polluting the names in the file.

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 3 and 4

I am sorry for the late answer, but the throwing test method needs to be in a block, for the `XCTAssertNoThrow` and `XCTAssertThrowsError` to work correctly, i.e. without the `do{}catch{}`.

So, your code will become, note the { } :

```
let expect = expectation(description: "Async network call")
SomeManager.executeCall { result in
    XCTAssertThrowsError({try CoreManager.method()}, "The method didn't throw")
    expect.fulfill()
}
waitForExpectations(timeout: 15.0, handler: nil)
```